# Applescript Photoshop Load Selection based on Layer

Tags: applescript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Anyone know if it is possible to load a selection of a layer. For Example I have two shapes on a transparent layer. I want to make a selection on those two shapes. Normally I can just hold command and click the layers thumbnail and have the selection. There is another long path through the selection drop down.

I have tried things like (just guessing at this point)

```
tell application id "com.adobe.photoshop"
    activate
        load selection of current layer of current document
    end tell
end tell
```

Anyone ever do this with Applescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way i could find to do this was to revert to javascript via the `do javaScript` command

Seems the javascript mode in PhotoShop has some lower level hooks that can solve this particular problem.

e.g,

```
set js_code to "function SelectTransparency(){
    var idChnl = charIDToTypeID('Chnl');
    var actionSelect = new ActionReference();
    actionSelect.putProperty(idChnl, charIDToTypeID('fsel'));
    var actionTransparent = new ActionReference();    
    actionTransparent.putEnumerated(idChnl, idChnl, charIDToTypeID('Trsp'));
   var actionDesc = new ActionDescriptor();
    actionDesc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), actionSelect);
    actionDesc.putReference( charIDToTypeID('T   '), actionTransparent);
    executeAction(charIDToTypeID('setd'), actionDesc, DialogModes.NO);
}

SelectTransparency();
"

tell application id "com.adobe.photoshop"
    activate
    do javascript js_code
end tell
```